# Wicket model object instance is changing

Tags: java, wicket

I have created a Wicket model like this:

```
IModel<MyObject> myModel = new Model<MyObject>(new MyObject());
```

In order to debug a problem I created this snippet:

```
modalWindow.setWindowClosedCallback(new ModalWindow.WindowClosedCallback() {
            public void onClose(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            System.out.println(myModel.getObject());
            }
        });
```

This print out a different object instance each time the onClose is invoked. Can someone please explain to me why this happens? Is this correct behavior? Shouldn't the myModel model object be the same instance every time?

Comment: How do your code pieces interact? Is a new 'myModel' created with a new `MyObject` for every window, or is there one global `myModel` that is used for every window? Can you show the code in a bit more context?

Comment: Actually there is not much more context to explain. This piece of code was created for debugging purposes only, to determine whether or not the model object is changed. The myModel is not used at all inside the modal window. Since you are asking - the object should have remained the same instance? (I am a Wicket-noob, you see).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your model and the containing MyObject are serialized along with the page. Thus the identityHasCode changes, logically it's still the same object.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you. By using a Panel instead, inside modalWindow, this is not happening anymore.